# Sql Alchemy before-select event

Tags: events, select, sqlalchemy

I am playing around with SQL Alchemy and I need to do some work before SQLA executes select statement. So I figured out that the best way would be to use SQLA Event, but I cant find a suitable before-select event. Is it there but I am poor at finding.

If its not there, can somebody tell me how to write my custom event?

Thx for any suggestions.
Best Regards
Gabe

Comment: What kind of work do you need to do there? Modify the query itself (like some general filters or eager-load some data)?

Comment: :van thx for reply. What I want to do is to grab each select on that table and give it my little modification before it is sent to DB

Comment: the nature of the "little modification" here is important.   Often you can get away with using a @compiles on the Select construct, if it's something that is simple and always on a certain table.   If you're in the ORM a Query subclass can also be used, see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So sorry for not writing for a while but some while ago I did what I wanted to do. I don`t no if it is an elegant way but it works.

So what I did is writing my own Session class:

```
class MySession(Session):

    def execute(self, clause, params=None, mapper=None, **kw):
        # Your magic with clause here
        return Session.execute(self, clause, params, mapper)
```

Then you need to create your session like this:

```
Session = sessionmaker(engine, class_ = MySession)
```

Hope that it will help someone who struggled with similar issue :)

Regards

P.s. Thanks everybody who contributed in this question.